# Вывод данных с массива

Tags: php, массивы

к примеру есть массив

`$array = [1, 0]`

И есть другой массив

```
$product = [
    [ 
        'title' => 'Macbook',
        'price' => 10000,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'IPhone',
        'price' => 8000,
    ],
];
```

Как вывести значения массива `$product` когда ключ массива `$product` = значения массива `$array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = [1, 0];
$product = [
    [ 
        'title' => 'Macbook',
        'price' => 10000,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'IPhone',
        'price' => 8000,
    ],
];


foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo "Продукт: ", $product[$arr]['title'], " | Цена: ", $product[$arr]['price'], "<br>";
}
```